# Organise the output in different levels by adding tabs

Tags: ocaml

My programs print lots of information as output. For a better readability, one way is to organise them in different levels by adding different numbers of tabs. For instance, the following layout can be realised by always printing a number of tabs before printing something, and the number of tabs can be controlled by a global reference variable.

```
level_1_begin
... ...
   level_2_begin
   ... ...
     level_3_begin
     ... ...
     level_3_end 
   level_2_end
... ...
   level_2_begin
   level_2_end
... ...
level_1_end
```

However, this way has a problem: when a text is very long and has to go to another line (because of the width of the window), it will ignore the tabs and start from the very left. For instance,

```
level_1_begin
... ...
   level_2_begin
   a very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very long line
   ... ...
   level_2_end
```

Instead, I want the display to be like this:

```
level_1_begin
... ...
   level_2_begin
   a very very very very very very very very very very 
   very very very very long line
   ... ...
   level_2_end
```

Does anyone know if OCaml has any solution to make it possible?

Comment: What is it that makes it "go to another line"? Viewing in a window with line-wrapping? Or is there some code somewhere that actually inserts a new line? If the latter, maybe you can change the code to obey the current indentation.

Comment: it means "viewing in a window with line-wrapping". So it is totally up to the width of the window: if the window is large enough, a long text does not go to another line...

Comment: Seems to me you can't solve this problem if arbitrary window widths are allowed. It would have to be solved by code in the widow. You can pre-wrap lines to some width using the Format module as suggested by @Drup.

Comment: The window width is more or less fixed (ie, my screen width), so pre-wrap lines to some width will be fine for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Format module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html). There is a tutorial on boxes [here](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/guides/format.en.html).